# Как сделать овальный блок для секции сайта

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой дизайн.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой овал внизу шапки сайта?

Comment: Вырезать в фотошопе, например?

Comment: Если не будет другого варианта то можно сделать такой PNG и вставить картинкой. Думаю может стоить попробовать сделать это через svg. Правда я сам не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Если что то не ясно спрашивайте ...

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 508 77" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern" width="3413.3332" height="2133.3332" patternTransform="matrix(.3 0 0 .3 -443 -183)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image width="3e3" height="2e3" style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhyFS.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(241 -54)">
  <path d="m-241 54h508l-.3 34c-164 56-333 57-507 0z" style="fill:url(#pattern)";/>
  <path d="m-132 69 276-.8c-3 6-3 10 3 13l-286-.8c3-2 7-4 7-12z" style="fill:#00ff00"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```